# Retroactive Kiddush Hachodesh according to Rambam

Tags: rambam, mishna, rosh-chodesh-new-month

[ראש השנה משנה ב ח](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Rosh_Hashanah.2.8)- וְעוֹד בָּאוּ שְׁנַיִם וְאָמְרוּ, רְאִינוּהוּ בִזְמַנּוֹ, וּבְלֵיל עִבּוּרוֹ לֹא נִרְאָה, וְקִבְּלָן רַבָּן גַּמְלִיאֵל. אָמַר רַבִּי דוֹסָא בֶּן הַרְכִּינָס, עֵדֵי שֶׁקֶר הֵן, הֵיאָךְ מְעִידִין עַל הָאִשָּׁה שֶׁיָּלְדָה, וּלְמָחָר כְּרֵסָהּ בֵּין שִׁנֶּיהָ. אָמַר לוֹ רַבִּי יְהוֹשֻׁעַ, רוֹאֶה אֲנִי אֶת דְּבָרֶיךָ:

Discussing what appears to be witnesses testifying about day 30 and day 31 at the same time.

On the question of what point testifying on day 31 about days 30 and 31, when the קידוש date has already passed, the רש"ש [says](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashash_on_Mishnah_Rosh_Hashanah.2.8.1)
במשנה ועוד באו שנים ואמרו ראינוהו בזמנו ובליל עיבורו ל"נ (והוא ליל ל"א כפירש"י לעיל ס"ד כ"ב וכ"נ מפירש"י כאן) וקבלן ר"ג. משמע דקיבלן אחר ליל עיבורו היינו ביום ל"א לקדש למפרע את יום הל'. ומזה אולי יצא לו להרמב"ם מש"כ בפ"ג מהל' קה"ח הל' ט"ז דמקדשין למפרע אפי' אחר ד' או ה' ימים. אך יש לדחוק דוקבלן ר"ג היינו קודם ליל עיבורו. אולם יש ראיה מגמ' (כ"ד) מעובר איצטריכא ליה כו' ופירש"י ואי תנא ה"ז מתקדש למחר ה"א לעולם מיומא קמא מתקנין מועדותיה והיינו דמתקדש למפרע. ולהט"א לקמן ברפ"ג אישתמיט במחכ"ת דברי הרמב"ם הללו וחדושי הרשב"א שם:

Quoting the רמב"ם [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Sanctification_of_the_New_Month.3.16?vhe=Torat_Emet_363):
רמב"ם הלכות קדוש החדש ג טז. וְאִם עָמְדוּ הָעֵדִים בְּעֵדוּתָן וְנִמְצֵאת מְכֻוֶּנֶת וַהֲרֵי הָעֵדִים אֲנָשִׁים יְדוּעִים וּנְבוֹנִים וְנֶחְקְרָה הָעֵדוּת כָּרָאוּי. מְקַדְּשִׁין אוֹתוֹ וְחוֹזְרִין וּמוֹנִין לְאוֹתוֹ הַחֹדֶשׁ מִיּוֹם שְׁלֹשִׁים הוֹאִיל וְנִרְאֶה הַיָּרֵחַ בְּלֵילוֹ:

Who appears to hold that retroactive קידוש is theoretically possible.

But if a retroactive קידוש is possible, then how do we explain:
[ראש השנה משנה ג א](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Rosh_Hashanah.3.1)- רָאוּהוּ בֵית דִּין וְכָל יִשְׂרָאֵל, נֶחְקְרוּ הָעֵדִים, וְלֹא הִסְפִּיקוּ לוֹמַר מְקֻדָּשׁ, עַד שֶׁחֲשֵׁכָה, הֲרֵי זֶה מְעֻבָּר.

Which implies the opposite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is asked by [Ritva to Rosh HaShanah 25b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ritva_on_Rosh_Hashanah.25b.5?lang=he), who writes that he doesn't know how to explain Rambam's words properly.

One answer (which I do not fully understand) is presented by [R. Chaim Yitzchak Korb](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%97%D7%A7_%D7%A7%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%91) in [Netivot Chaim to Kiddush HaChodesh 3:15](https://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=46751&rid=2506). He distinguishes between a case where no witnesses came at all on Day 30, in which case a retroactive *kiddush* is allowed, and a case where witnesses did come on Day 30, but *beit din* were not able to sanctify on that day, in which case a retroactive *kiddush* is not allowed due to the concept of *dichui*.

Another answer is suggested by [R. Nahum Rabinovitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nahum_Rabinovitch) in his [Yad Peshutah to Kiddush HaChodesh 2:8](https://www.ybm.org.il/upload/Rambam_Yomi/03%20zmanim/08%20kidush_hachodesh/02_yad.pdf#page=23). He believes that Rambam distinguished between the day which is celebrated as *rosh chodesh* (in terms of offering the *korban musaf*) and the first day of the month which is to be used for calendrical purposes. Therefore, when witnesses come on Day 30, but *beit din* can't sanctify the month until Day 31, while Day 31 is celebrated as *rosh chodesh*, it is actually the **second** day of the month for calendrical purposes, because we do indeed say that retroactively Day 30 was the first day of the new month.